# How to know whether a c++ source file has a main function or not?

Tags: c++, makefile

Does anyone have ideas about checking the existence of the main function in a c++ source, as I want to write a somewhat automatic makefile, so that the c++ sources with main function will be linked while those without main function won't link.

Lexical or grammar parsing may be not suitable for this simple task.

Any existing command line tools or libraries will be much helpful to this automatic task.

Thanks for any ideas!

The makefile file:

```
VPATH = include
CPPFLAGS += -I include
CFLAGS += -I include

C_SOURCE := $(shell find . -iname '*.c')
CPP_SOURCE := $(shell find . -iname '*.cpp')
D_OBJ := $(subst .cpp,.d, $(CPP_SOURCE))
EXE := $(subst .c,, $(C_SOURCE))
EXE += $(subst .cpp,, $(CPP_SOURCE))

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE)

include $(D_OBJ) 

$(D_OBJ): %.d: %.cpp
    $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.temp;
    auto_depend_gen $@ "$@.temp" > $@; 
    rm -rf $@.temp

#print_msg:
#   @printf "$(EXE)\n"
#   @printf "$(D_OBJ)\n"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm $(EXE) $(D_OBJ)
```

So this is an automatic dependency generation makefile. With this makefile, I need not modify the makefile every time I add a C++ source file. The headers are determined by the "gcc -MM" command and the object files I want to link share the same name with the header files except the suffixes. auto_depend_gen is a program written by myself which just removes the .o suffix of the first line of the file generated by "gcc -MM".

Some source files have main function, while some do not, so comes this problem.

Maybe a more general question is: while a Java project can be built automatically with more than one of the .class files having a main function, but C++ cannot. So I just want to solve it.

Appreciate more comments!

Comment: simple task? I don't see it that way... if you wrote the code you want to compile, the most obvious approach is, instead of parsing every file to see if they've got a main function defined, would be to name the file with the main function "main.cpp"

Comment: Linked against what?  Why do you need to treat `main` differently?

Comment: since its unlikely to change on a given project, I'd just specify the cpp file with main as a command line argument or a config setting at the top of the make file.

Comment: I want to compile all the the source files under a directory, and I don't want to modify the makefile every time I add a file, so I write a automatic dependency generation makefile which means all the header dependencies are determined by "gcc -MM" command. And the object files I want to link have the same name with the headers. But some files have main functions while some do not, so comes the problems.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intent here.  Are you saying that you have a folder full of C files, some of which have main functions?  And that for every file with a main function, you want to create a corresponding executable?  And that every such executable should be created by linking the corresponding .o file along with all the remaining .o files that don't contain main?

Comment: Not all the remaining .o files, but these .o files corresponding to the headers that the file includes. For example: if a plus.cpp file contains #include "my_math.h", and plus.cpp contains a main function, then plus.o should be linked with my_math.o (suppose there is my_math.cpp with no main function) to produce the executive file. In this way, the build process is OK even new files are added.

Comment: Using nm puts the real work down to the compiler.

Comment: Care to post your final `Makefile` and your `auto_depend_gen`? I find this interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `nm` to list symbols in object file. Check if `main` is one of them.

Comment: If nm executed before object files stripped or packed, it should be OK.

Comment: Or purposely generate object files with symbols for nm

Answer (score 1):

This Linux command should give you a list of files with the main() function:

```
grep -Er 'main\s*\(' * | cut -d':' -f1
```

You should handle the case where this list have more than one file.

Comment: Er... but if the main occurred in comments and string literals, this command would fail.

Comment: I just want to find a more precise solution.